# Comma Separated comparison in excel or google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have 2 values in 2 different cells as below,

`Cell1 = a,b,c,d,e,f`

and

`Cell2 = f,a,d,c,b,e`

Both the cells may contain same vales but not in exact order.

How Can I compare both in excel sheet or a google sheet and get to know if both the cells have same values irrespective of the order of the values.

I tried some methods but they are not working.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is split them, transpose, sort then join again before comparing

#### Formula:

```
=join(",", sort(transpose(split(A1, ","))))=join(",", sort(transpose(split(B1, ","))))
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

Try this excel function,

In `D1`, formula copied down :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(CODE(MID(A1,ROW($1:$99),1)&0))=SUMPRODUCT(CODE(MID(B1,ROW($1:$99),1)&0))
```

[image]